# C strange if statement syntax

Tags: c, if-statement

I saw this `if` statement and I am not sure exactly how that works, what is being compared with what? Is there a lack of `&&` or `||`? The parens are confusing me.

```
if ((list->func)((list->head)->dataPointer, newOb) < 0) {
```

Comment: This has redundant parentheses, it could have been written `if ( list->func(list->head->dataPointer, newOb) < 0 )`

Comment: The same could also have been rewritten as `result = list->func(list->head->dataPointer, newOb);` followed by `if(result < 0)`. Most often it is a good idea to split complex expressions in several lines, for readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is being compared with what? The parens are confusing me.

The result of the part between `if(` and `)` is being compared with 0, like in every if statement.

> Is there a lack of && or ||?

I don't see any && or ||

> The parens are confusing me.

What `(list->func)((list->head)->dataPointer, newOb)` does is (not necessarily in this order):

- Evaluate `list->func`
- Evaluate `(list->head)->dataPointer`
- **Call** `list->func` passing the two arguments `(list->head)->dataPointer` and `newOb`.

The result of this is then compared to 0 because it's what's between the `if(` and `)`.

Comment: Thank you, the parens made it hard to read. All makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the first set of parentheses are indicating that list is a pointer to an object which has a member called func.  func is a function.  So (list->func) is a function call.  The function apparently takes two arguments.  The first argument that is being passed in is (list->head)->dataPointer.  (list->head) indicates that the object that the pointer called list  is pointing at has a member called head.  head is also a pointer, and it points at an object with a member called dataPointer.  The second argument that is being passed to the function (list->func) is newOb.  The function (list->func) is apparently returning some sort of number value, probably an int.
The code could be rewritten as:
    if( list->func( list->head->dataPointer, newOb ) < 0 )
if that helps you see what is going on.

Comment: `(list->func)` is not a function call.  The function call is indicated by the `()` operator which appears immediately after that.

Comment: Well, technically the entire expression (list->func)( stuff, more stuff) is the function call, but it doesn't take away from my larger point that list->func is a function, and it is being called.